# Help finding a star formed by a regular pentagons segments that intersect to form an equilateral decagon

Tags: geometry

How can I find $"k"$ in the function $A(x) = kx^2$ when said function describes the area of a star formed by a regular pentagons segments which are extended to create an equilateral decagon?

The sides of the equilateral decagon each measure $x.$

I am extremely confused by this problem, and the teacher did not provide a diagram to go with it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the teacher did not provide a diagram, you should do so.  Can you draw a regular pentagon?  Then make each of the sides into lines instead of line segments.  You should see the five pointed star, which has ten sides and is a decagon.  All the sides are equal.  Now if you draw from the points of the star to the center you make lots of right triangles, which can help with computing the area.  The figure below has the pentagon with sides of $2$ and the star with sides of about $3\frac 14$.  The bottom point of the star appears to be at $(-1,-3)$.  Is that true?  If so, it will be useful for computing the area and the sides.

[image]